# Make image stick to list in center of webpage

Tags: html

I'm trying to make an image stuck to the left side on the same height. However, it just won't work. The image is smaller in my actual version of the code bhut that shouldn't affect the output. Here's my code.

```css
#nav {
  text-align: center;
  background: #b7b7b7;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
}

#nav li:hover {
  background: #662282;
}

#nav li.app {
  background: #f28a24;
}

#nav li.home {
  background: #662282;
}

#nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: gillsans-light;
  font-size: 16px;
}

<!-- image here -->
#nav img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="http://www.#.com"> <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/512/099310-feedburner-logo.png">
    <ul>
      <li class="home"><a href="http://www.#.com/#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="cloud"><a href="http://www.#.com/cloud">Cloud</a></li>
      <li class="color"><a href="http://www.#.com/#color">Color</a></li>
      <li class="features"><a href="http://www.#.com/features">Features</a></li>
      <li class="tools"><a href="http://www.#.com/#tools">Tools</a></li>
      <li class="solutions"><a href="http://www.#.com/solutions">Solutions</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="http://www.#.com/about-us">About us</a></li>
      <li class="contact"><a href="http://www.#.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="app"><a href="http://app.#.cloud/">APP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE TEST IMAGE**

Comment: Please show us your html.

Comment: share the **code you have tried that makes the image slide** including the HTML

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Updated the OP!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran your code to see if I could replicate the issue, but if I'm reading your question correctly, it looks like everything is working as you desire: [view fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nt5wufrr/2/)

I replaced your image URL with a random logo from google images just so I'd have an image to try.

The CSS rule `text-align: center` that you have for `#nav` is centering your image properly.

One thing I did notice is that you did not close your `<a>` tag:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="http://www.#.com"> <img src="http://#.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png">
```

However, changing this did not affect the styling of your page.

**Edit:**
SOLUTION based on OP's comment below:

[View updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nt5wufrr/3/)

In order to achieve what you want, one solution is to include the image as the first list item so that it falls within the flow of your nav links:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.#.com">
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/512/099310-feedburner-logo.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer which provides a solution to the question though the problem is not reproducible and shouldn't be answered at all.

Comment: Thank you for testing this but what you produced in the fiddle isn't what i'm asking for. Currently, the image is stuck to the left hand side of the page and it needs to be moved to the left side of the list on the same line. What you have shown is the image above the menu, however still centered.

Comment: @Rob sorry about that; I do not yet have the ability to comment on posts.

Comment: Still, don't post comments in the answer section. Please delete this.

Comment: @FredOnes please see update. Hopefully that's more of what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for the solution ;)